# java.util.Arrays.sort doesn't sort an array of doubles properly

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, double

Link to the full test case:

[test case](https://hr-testcases-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/21180/input04.txt?response-content-type=text%2Fplain&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAR6O7GJNX5DNFO3PV%2F20231013%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20231013T121913Z&X-Amz-Expires=7200&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=df6f3cd744b9f3435188eb3b7ceb637fb209b2688ff12206051a99cc09d75bcc)

The test case consists of 2500 values, all being above 0.
The problem I have is: It doesn't sort properly.
Neither with a coded sorting algorithm, nor with the Arrays.sort function.

How does this happen and how do I fix this? The result I'm getting is the following:

The output shows the following:

0.0
0.0
0.0
46.0
54.0
118.0
141.0
220.0
259.0
273.0
...

There are no zeros in the array. Also the amount of 3 digit numbers is way lower in the test case than in the sorted array. This is the snippet for the code.

The interesting thing being: I've debugged the input already, reading in the input works without problems, however after the sorting, the whole array is broken and the values are all incorrect.

This is the code snippet:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT. Your class should be named Solution. */
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            int n = sc.nextInt(); 
            double[] inarr = new double[n];
            double sum = 0;
            
            for (int i = 0; i<n; i++){
                if (sc.hasNextDouble()){
                    inarr[i] = sc.nextDouble();
                }
                
                sum += inarr[i];
            }
            
            // for (int i = 0; i<n; i++){
            //     System.out.println(inarr[i]);
            // }
            
            Arrays.sort(inarr);
            
            for (int i = 0; i<n; i++){
                System.out.println(inarr[i]);
            }
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I find that hard to believe, that a built-in sort function would "invent" new numbers ... I suspect, there is something wrong with your input (or input processing). Print your `inarr` before sorting and check if it contains the expected values. And why are you even reading doubles when all of your input seem to be integers?

Comment: @derprischer I did. And it worked. I already wrote that in the question description above. I tested exchanging the int values for doubles in case that could be an error, I'm not that experienced in programming to specifically know whether these things could affect the output or not however it doesn't seem to have made a difference.

Comment: Are you sure your reading is correct? Maybe its locale issue?

Comment: Your link does not work for me (and us, I believe).

Comment: We need a [mre], please? Which would include the values to be sorted being hard-coded in the program. Or at the very least the full input being limited to less than 10 numbers if possible, and being given in the question itself. (Obviously, if you can only reproduce the error with 100 numbers, initialize the array with 100 numbers, but do it in the code, not by reading input.)

Comment: Like @derpirscher says, `Arrays.sort` does not make up or invent new data. If there are zeroes in your array after sorting, they were there before sorting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One issue could be

```
for (int i = 0; i<n; i++){
    if (sc.hasNextDouble()){
        inarr[i] = sc.nextDouble();
    }
    sum += inarr[i];
}
```

I don't know what environment you are running this in, but if there is any issue with your stdin you may skip values here. Ie, if `sc.hasNextDouble()` returns `false` for any reason you are still incrementing your `i` and the current place in the `inarray` stays at `0` ...

Add a counter and check how many values you are actually reading

```
int readCount = 0;
for (int i = 0; i<n; i++){
    if (sc.hasNextDouble()){
        inarr[i] = sc.nextDouble();
        readCount++;
    }
    sum += inarr[i];
} 
System.out.println(readCount);
```

In your case you probably will receive a `readCount` that is less than `n`. Again, as we don't know your environment or how you get your data into stdin, I cannot help you solve this issue. But I can assure you, `Arrays.sort` won't create new numbers in the array.

Comment: _+1_.  And, realistically they wouldn't even need the _hasNextDouble_ call, because the _loop_ is conditional to _n_.   _int i = 0; do inarr[i] = sc.nextDouble(); while (++i < n);_

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I seemed to have judged the input being read in to be correct too quickly. Indeed, there were some inputs missing but this is fixed now.